# how to use div in echo code

Tags: php, html, css

i have below code, i want use div on it and then use class , but when i use div, it show me error at WordPress, i think use div on it wrongly...

```
$title = $instance['title'];
$title = apply_filters('widget_title', $title);
echo  $before_title.'<img src="'.includes_url().'/images/rss.png">'.$title.$after_title."\n";
//echo "l:".$instance['layouttype'];
```

if i cant use div on it, so how i can use style like background-color on it?

Please help me how i can resolve it?

thanks.

Comment: What error? And what do you mean with "on it" ? Like so: `echo '<div class="myClass">  ..... </div>';`?

Comment: `echo  '<div>'.$before_title.'<img src="'.includes_url().'/images/rss.png">'.$title.$after_title.'</div>\n';`

Answer (score 2):

You can use div tag like any other tags. 
In your example this will look something like this:

```
$title = $instance['title'];
$title = apply_filters('widget_title', $title);
echo  "<div style='background-color: red;'>" . $before_title.'<img src="'.includes_url().'/images/rss.png">'.$title.$after_title. "</div>" . "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the example how to use div in echo code.

```
<?php
echo '<div class="">';

echo '</div>'; 
?>
```

Hope this helpful.